# How to pass optional list of objects or string

Tags: c#

In my project used need pass string or some time pass object for example

```
DropDownData(new List<object>(){"a"})
```

or

but i can't pass in below format

```
DropDownData({id="a",text:"a"})
```

i have create wrapper class as

```
List<object> DropDownData = new List<object>();
```

please help me how to pass both type based on user needs string / object in list.

Comment: Why you don't use key value pair? as it would keep the implementation simple?

Comment: hi adil, if you use keyvalue pair , we need to declare key and value that means List<keyvaluepair(int,string)(1,"a")> must be add both but my scanario optional some time pass List<string>("a") in some time List<object>{id='1', text='a'}

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not entirely clear, but you can use method [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) to add any object that you want:

```
// initialize your list
List<object> DropDownData = new List<object>();  

// add string with value "a"
DropDownData.Add("a");  

// adds anonymous object with 2 properties
DropDownData.Add(new {id="a", text="a"});
```

After running the code your List contains 2 items.